# Subscribing in services

Tags: angular, observable

Wanting to understand best practice in angular. In general, should one subscribe to observables in a service in order to store values or is it better to subscribe only in relevant components? If it is OK to subscribe in a service for this reason, should the subscriptions be done in the service's constructor or is it best to avoid this?

Comment: subscribe to observable where needed (with exception for http observables). Period. Does not matter when.

Comment: You can’t return anything from within a subscribe, so if you need to pass data to a component for example, you wouldn’t be able to effectively.

Comment: Do whatever makes sense in terms of your app and its organization.  If you're subscribing to something from a service, there should be a reason.  If you're subscribing to something from a component, there should be a reason.  I'm of the belief that you should subscribe where you want to consume them for some purpose.

What does NOT make sense IMHO is to use a service just to "store values".  If you're not doing something to those values and you're just storing them (i.e., maybe for organization purposes), it seems like an unnecessary layer adding unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to not subscribe `Observable` in component logic neither in service unless you explicitly `unsubscribe()` subscriptions.

A better approach is to use `async` pipe provided by Angular.

```
 this.data$ = this.myDataService
      .get()
      .pipe(
        map(res => res.data),
        tap(x => console.log(x))
      );
```

Then in template :

```
<div *ngFor="let data of (data$ | async)">
  Hello {{data}}
</div>
```

This approach has a lot of benefits like cleaner code, avoid memory leak, best performance, maintainability, easy migration to `OnPush` change detection strategy and powerful usage of RxJS.

I know it can be hard to understand for beginner but I often see complex Angular application because of a bad usage of RxJS.

Comment: yes I agree this is for the most part the best way, thank you